# How to spread children that display an XML shape evenly in a GridLayout (with maximum possible size)?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, android-imagebutton, android-shape

**Here is what i want:**

I have a `GridLayout` inside of a `ConstraintLayout`, to which I add multiple rows and columns of custom `ImageButtons` (`BoardCells`) dynamically.
The ImageButtons display circles using a `shape` XML file (code below).

I want the BoardCells to have equal width and height so the shape really is a circle and not an oval.
I also want the BoardCells to take as much space as possible on the screen and spread evenly.

**Here is what I tried:**

I tried a fixed size (in dp) for the BoardCells and setting layout_width of the GridLayout to `wrap_content`, but that will only work on different screens that are rather similar and does not use the space optimal. [Screenshot of the GridLayout with fixed size BoardCells.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFv0E.png)

When I dont't set size for the shape and BoardCell then nothing gets displayed at all, doen't matter if GridLayout has `match_parent`, `wrap_content` or `0dp`.

So I tried to give all BoardCells the same weight inside of the GridLayout like this:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f);
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f);
this.setLayoutParams(params);
this.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

But setting `column-` and `rowSpec` does not keep the ratio so I don't get circles (which makes sense).
[Screenshot of the GridLayout with column- and rowSpec set to 1 for every BoardCell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3VRz.png)

So I tried to only set columnSpec and setting the `ScaleType` to `CENTER` or `CENTER_INSIDE`, hoping this would keep the ratio but stretch as much as possible.
But this only stretches horizontally and takes the fixed size vertically.
[Screenshot of the GridLayout with columnSpec set to 1 and ScaleType CENTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpqo.png)

Then I thought I would implement an `onLayoutChangedListener` for the GridLayout, but trying to add children to GridLayout inside of `onLayoutChanged` resultet in "requestLayout() improperly called" errors in my log.

My last idea is to first display an empty GridLayout and only when the user presses a button to start the game (the button exists anyways because you may play multiple rounds), and the view is already inflated and displayed, I receive the width and height of GridLayout and calculate the biggest possible size for the BoardCells.
But this approach does not seem to be best practise.

Now I don't know what would be the right thing to do.
Did I do something wrong or is there any solution that I didn't think of at all?
Should I experiment with a bunch of emulated devices and create XML shape files for different screen sizes?
Is the dynamic approach okay?

**Here is the relevant Code:**

XML layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/wood"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/board_cells"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline70"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline8"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I fill this GridLayout with custom ImageButtons with the following Code:

```
gridLayoutBoard.setUseDefaultMargins(true);
gridLayoutBoard.setRowCount(10);
gridLayoutBoard.setColumnCount(6);
for (int i = gridLayoutBoard.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gridLayoutBoard.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        if (j == 0 || j == 5) {
            Indikator text= new TextView;
            gridLayoutBoard.addView(text);
        } else {
            BoardCell boardCell = new BoardCell(this);
            gridLayoutBoard.addView(boardCell);
        }
    }
}
```

The ImageButtons (BoardCells) set their background to this selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/cell_solid"/>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/cell_gradient"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

which uses the following solid shape and a gradient with the same size and shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey_cell_dings" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```